# How to use inheritance to form a generic callback function pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-pointers

I am trying to write a function that would take in a generic function pointer as an argument.
Suppose you have a `class A` and its derivatives like below

```
class A {
};
class A1: public A {
};
class A2: public A {
};
class A3: public A {
};
```

I have another function

```
void registerCallback(std::function<void(A*)> func_ptr) {
}

int main() {
   std::function<void(A1*)> fptr= [&](A1*) {
       cout << "dummy" <<endl;
   };
   registerCallback(fptr); /// throws error 
}
```

It tells you, cannot convert `std::function<void(A*)>` to `std::function<void(A1*)>`
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Who is the parameter for? These days I'll capture the user argument in a lambda or with `std::bind` (in increasingly rare cases) and the resulting `std::function` has zero arguments.

Comment: A `std::function<void(A*)>` can accept an `A2*` but `fptr` can't, so clearly `fptr` doesn't satisfy the interface requirement of `std::function<void(A*)>`.  You'll need to re-think your design, but there's not enough context in this question to say what design would be better.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I solve this problem?

You can use `A*` instead of `A1*` in the definition of `fptr`.

```
std::function<void(A*)> fptr= [&](A*) {
    cout << "dummy" <<endl;
   };
```

---

It is instructive to understand why your code is erroneous, not just from a syntactic point of view but also from a semantic point of view.

From a syntactic point of view, `A1*` can be used where `A*` where is expected -- it is an automatic pointer conversion. However, `std::function<void(A1*)>` cannot be used where `std::function<void(A*)>` is expected. There is no automatic conversion.

It's more important to understand the semantic problem if that was not
a syntactic error. Let's say for the sake of this discussion that the language/compiler accepted your code.  Let's take the code a bit further. Update your code to the following:

```
class A {
};

class A1: public A {
    public:
        int int_var;
};

class A2: public A {
    public:
        double double_var;
};


class A3: public A {
    public:
        std::string string_var;
};

static std::function<void(A*)> registered_function_ptr;


void registerCallback(std::function<void(A*)> func_ptr) {
    registered_function_ptr = fun_ptr;
}


void callRegisteredFunction(A* a_ptr) {
    registered_function_ptr(a_ptr);
}

int main() {

    std::function<void(A1*)> fptr= [&](A1* a1_ptr) {
        // Expecting a pointer to an A1 object.
        // Should be able to use members of A1.
        cout << "int_var: " << a1_ptr->int_var << endl;
   };


   registerCallback(fptr);

    A2 a2;
    a2.double_var = 20;
    // Syntactically correct.
    callRegisteredFunction(&a2);

    A3 a3;
    a3.string_var = "Some string";
    // Also syntactically correct.
    callRegisteredFunction(&a3);
}
```

When `callRegisteredFunction` is executed, it calls the registered function. In this case it is `fptr`. `fptr` expects a pointer to an `A1` object but we are able to call it indirectly with objects that are different -- they don't have `int_var`. Instead, they have `double_var` and `string_var`. That will definitely lead to undefined behavior. The compiler and the language are preventing you falling into that trap.

Comment: Fantastic explanation! Not sure how one would acquire such subtle knowledge with c++ template

Comment: @user3443615, it takes a willingness to dive deeper into the language once in a while, and some blood and sweat :)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `fptr` as a callable object with parameter of basic type - `std::function<void(A*)>`. It will still accept all classes (publicly) derived from `A`:

```
int main() {
    std::function<void(A*)> fptr= [&](A*) {
        std::cout << "dummy" << std::endl;
    };
    A1 *a = new A1{};
    
    fptr(a); // all good
}
```